# Can't Install Pyheif python library

Tags: python, pip, pyheif

So, I have a Python project to convert and Compress images/pictures. I want this program to support the HEIC/HEIF format. I read about the library to use, and it said I could use Pyheif for the project. But, when it came to the installation, I found this issue.

[pip error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR46O.jpg)

Previously, I researched that I could use

```
Imageio Library
```

to support those formats. But it doesn't. So, right now, I want to try with Pyheif, but this new issue comes.

I'm using Python 3.12 in Windows, and not only that, but I need help to install some other libraries like TensorFlow and others. I can't install them.

I tried installing the Microsoft C++ build tools, but they are not working either. I tried to downgrade my Python version, and it is not working, too.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in https://github.com/carsales/pyheif/issues/2#issuecomment-886469620 ?

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly.
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install --use-pep517`

Answer (score 0):

This error message `_DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.` shows that you're having an issue with the version of your Setuptools. You can check the version of Setuptools in your python interpreter using:

```
import setuptools
print(setuptools.__version__)
```

If it's above version 58.2.0, then you might want to downgrade to a last version that worked using:

```
pip install setuptools==58.2.0
```

This should fix your errors and you should be able to install Pyheif package.